# How to use lein to manage the dependency of a dependency?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Should I create a local repository to change the dependencies of a dependency in my project?

I have a clojure project that is using docjure.  docjure contains a dependency on poi 3.6.

Because of a bug in generated Excel files I am reading, I have a local version of poi 3.8 that I hacked to workaround the bug.

It's easy enough to stick my poi 3.8 jars into my projects lib/ directory so that my project will run ok at the repl.

But, lein deps (or jar and uberjar) happily cleans the lib/ directory and reinstalls the 3.6 versions of poi, breaking my build.

I think the probable solution is two-fold:

1 - put my hacked poi 3.8 into a local repository
2 - create my own local copy of docjure and update it's dependencies to point to that local repository.

I am looking for confirmation that this is the "right thing" to do in this case or someone to point out that it is much easier to just do something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth reading Leiningen's [Repeatability](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability) wiki page if you haven't already. To quote part of it:

> If the code is public, you should open a bug report with upstream to get them to publish it in a public repository like Clojars, Sonatype, or Maven Central, depending on the project. If they are resistant or too slow it's always possible to publish "Clojars forks"; see lein help deploying for further details there.

The ultimate solution is to try and get your changes pushed upstream. Then you can depend on the version you need, and I *think* Leiningen will prefer that version if it's higher than the transitive version.

---

Another option might be to include your jar in a safe (checked-in) directory. Then write a plugin that can [hook into a built-in task](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/preview/doc/PLUGINS.md#hooks) and copy the jar to your lib directory for you. I really don't know if this will be successful, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Repeatability page, Jeremy.  The hack I put in place in poi removes an (correctly detected) Exception condition.  The root problem is that the Excel file is incorrectly formatted internally.  The poi reader correctly detects this specific case.  So its not really a fix, but rather a bad workaround.

Comment: I may try out the plugin hook, just because it looks snazzy. Thanks for the link. Ultimately, I'll probably create a local repository simply for support/maintenance reasons.